# How to add a Send Email Activity to an Automation with FuelSDK-Python?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, automationstudio, send-email, python

I unable to associate an Email Send Activity when creating an automation in Fuel-SDK Python. Below is my props dictionary setup. When posted the Automation is created but there is no Send Email activity in it. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

```
automation.props = {"CustomerKey":"AUTO TEST", "ScheduledTime":"2019-05-30T09:30:10-05:00", "Name":"AUTO TEST", "AutomationType":"scheduled", "Description":"AUTO TEST", "CategoryID":"19611", "AutomationTasks":{"AutomationTask":{"Name":"040319-test", "AutomationTaskType":"EmailSendDefition", "Activities":{"Activity":{"ObjectID":"7136259f-3f56-e911-a2cc-1402ec93869c", "Name":"040319-test", "ActivityObject":{"CustomerKey":"040319-test", "ObjectID":"7136259f-3f56-e911-a2cc-1402ec93869c"}}}}}}
```

Comment: What "Automation" are you referring to?

Comment: @BrianMiller I am referring to a scheduled automation in the Sales Force Marketing Cloud Automation Studio

Comment: Thanks - I updated your tags to say `marketing-cloud` so people have more context when reading the question